# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityEngine' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make a simple game using unity and C# with vs code. But when I try to build and run the program; it shows "error CS0246: The type or namespace name
'UnityEngine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

and

" error CS0246: The type or namespace nam
e 'MonoBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I tried to fix the error "preferences -> External tools -> External script editors -> vs code"
but its not work.

But c# works in the random program correctly. When I run any unity scripts; its show error.

code sample in the below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string ab = "sh";
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(ab);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the namespaces inside the scripts that the errors appears. On top you will see all the namespaces, check if the namespace "using UnityEnginge;" or whatever the error says that you are missing if are actually missing from the script. If it does missing then add it. Also if you can share any of your scripts here, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Do the scripts compile correctly in Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open "visual studio installer" and click on "Modify" on the version (that has been selected in "Unity>Edit>Preferences>External Tools>External Script Editor"), after clicking on modify make sure under "Workloads>Gaming" -> "Game development with Unity" is checked(if not do so).
After that close all windows of unity and visual studio and open again your project and go to "Unity>Edit>Preferences>External Tools" click on "Regenerate project files" button.
That'll resolve your issue!